# sqlalchemy deferred column loading - does not appear any more efficient

Tags: performance, sqlalchemy, loading, deferred

I have been trying to optimize a query and despite the effort, it doesn't seem that the following two queries have substantially different performance. Is it possible that the complexity of the ORM mapped objects are replacing any gains made at the DBAPI? If so, is there a solution?

```
baseContactQuery = contact.query.options(Load(contact).load_only(contact.user_id, contact.organization_contact, contact.relationship_strength, contact.full_name, contact.first_name, contact.last_name)).\
        options(selectinload(contact.organization_references).load_only(organization_contact_reference.contact_sharing_level)).\
        options(selectinload(contact.jobs).load_only(job.is_primary, job.role).options(selectinload(job.tied_company).load_only(company.name), lazyload('*'))).\
        options(selectinload(contact.emails).load_only(email.email, email.is_primary)).\
        options(selectinload(contact.contact_user).load_only(user.id).selectinload(user.organization_references).load_only(organization_user_reference.default_contact_sharing_level))
```

vs.

```
baseContactQuery = contact.query.\
    options(selectinload(contact.organization_references)).\
    options(selectinload(contact.jobs)).\
    options(selectinload(contact.emails)).\
    options(selectinload(contact.contact_user).selectinload(user.organization_references))
```

Comment: If these turn into SQL, let's see the SQL.

Comment: So I just compared the two and it seems to slow down once a bunch of filters are added (not shown in the baseContactQuery). Here's the SQL that is generated with all the filters included.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YD3l6EHHhM7E5cZZG-LPB9_nmsTdtX9oy8eBdEZcDgg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For sufficiently large tables, adding filters (`WHERE` criteria) means the db engine must do more work, so the query itself will take longer.  Particularly if the right indexes are not in place.  So you need to first of all establish how much time is being spent in the db before deciding where to optimise.

Answer (score 1):

I see some cases of

```
a AND b OR c
```

Make sure you want `(a AND b) OR c`, not `a AND (b OR c)`

`OR` is hard to optimize.

For `organization_contact_reference`:

```
INDEX(contact_id, contact_sharing_level)
```

Unless you have "ascii_quotes" turned on, this should be a syntax error:

```
WHERE  "user".id = ...
```

`organization_user_reference` needs

```
INDEX(user_id, organization_id, default_contact_sharing_level)
```

`ORDER BY  job.is_primary DESC, job.start_time DESC` *may* benefit from

```
INDEX(is_primary, start_time)
```

Not "sargeable":  `... AND  lower(email.email) IN ...`  Use a suitable `COLLATION` on `email` so that you don't need to use `LOWER()`.